# SqlDataAdapter not updating rows in Database

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am using SqlDataAdapter to update my dataTable which I had queried from Database in another method and in that method there were columns, Status and Is_processed which were updated.
Now, I want these changes to be persisted (updated) in Database. Following is what  have done to achieve:

**Code**

```
 batchSize = 10;

string cmd;

    int updatedRows;
    try
    {
        string connString = db.ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter())
        {
            cmd = "UPDATE IMPORTED_ACCOUNTS SET STATUS = @Status , IS_PROCESSED = @IsProcessed " +
                   ", CREATED_ON = @CreatedOn , CREATED_BY = @CreatedBy , UPDATED_ON = @UpdatedOn , UPDATED_BY = @UpdatedBy " +


 "WHERE CONVENTIONAL_ACCOUNT = @ConAcct";
        adapter.UpdateCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", "Status");
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsProcessed", SqlDbType.Bit, 1, dTable.Columns["IsProcessed"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn",SqlDbType.DateTime,30, dTable.Columns["CreatedOn"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", dTable.Columns["CreatedBy"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn",SqlDbType.DateTime,30, dTable.Columns["UpdatedOn"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedBy", dTable.Columns["UpdatedBy"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConAcct", dTable.Columns["ConventionalAccount"].ColumnName);

        cmd = "INSERT INTO IMPORTED_ACCOUNTS ([STATUS],[IS_PROCESSED],[CREATED_ON],[CREATED_BY],[UPDATED_ON],[UPDATED_BY], CONVENTIONAL_ACCOUNT) " +
              "VALUES (@Status , @IsProcessed, @CreatedOn, @CreatedBy, @UpdatedOn, @UpdatedBy, @ConAcct) ";
        adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
        adapter.InsertCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", dTable.Columns["Status"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@IsProcessed", SqlDbType.Bit, 1, dTable.Columns["IsProcessed"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@CreatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, dTable.Columns["CreatedOn"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedBy", dTable.Columns["CreatedBy"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@UpdatedOn", SqlDbType.DateTime, 30, dTable.Columns["UpdatedOn"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UpdatedBy", dTable.Columns["UpdatedBy"].ColumnName);
        adapter.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ConAcct", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, dTable.Columns["ConventionalAccount"].ColumnName);

        cmd = "DELETE FROM IMPORTED_ACCOUNTS WHERE CONVENTIONAL_ACCOUNT = @ConAcct";
        adapter.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand(cmd, conn);
        adapter.DeleteCommand.UpdatedRowSource = UpdateRowSource.OutputParameters;
        adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ConAcct", dTable.Columns["ConventionalAccount"].ColumnName);
        adapter.UpdateBatchSize = batchSize;
        updatedRows = adapter.Update(dTable);  // point where code breaks
    }
    return updatedRows;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return 0;
}
```

**Error**

It ends up with the following error in catch block:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ACCTS'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.IMPORTED_ACCOUNTS'.

**Comment**
Why is it trying to insert rows in database when they should be updated as they already exists in the Database? 
What are the conditions for adapter.Update(dTable) method, when it triggers Update rather Insert?

Can't figure out...
Help is indeed appreciated!

Comment: Check `RowState` of `DataRows` you're trying to update. If they has `Added` rowstate - then dataadapter will try to insert appropriate records.

Comment: I just checked RowState property and yes it has 'Added' value. What should I do now? Make it null?

Comment: Have you checked here:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/z1z2bkx2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Oh its a readOnly property. So how could I stop it from inserting 'Added'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In .NET `DataAdapter` makes database changes according to `DataRow.RowState` property.

In the case when it has `Added` value - dataadapter will try to insert records.
If you need to update records - then this property should has `Modified` value.

You can't directly set values od `RowState`. For example, it has been set to `Added` automatically when you're adding rows to your dataTable.

Hovewer, you still can indirectly modify this value. To do this, you should call `DataRow.AcceptChanges` for thouse datarows you need to update, this will set `RowState` to `Unchanged`. Then you should modify anything in these datarows, and in this case they will have `RowState = Modified`.

Comment: I have a database table that I am trying to get to update based on if the user changes the Description on an item. I have all the adapters and commandbuilders set up as well as a. if/elseif/then statement to go through the table I am using as the update table and change the rowstates to Added or Modified as needed. However, the database item description never updates. the Adapter.Update() inserts fine but never updates the table in question.

Comment: @ARidder101 it is almost impossible to help you without having a look into your actual code. Create a new question, provide your code sample - and somebody surely will help you with your problem.

Comment: I had created a question not long after I wrote this comment and after doing a little debug mode code tracing i figured out what i was doing wrong and posted the answer on my question. I was using a new DataTable that had a previous value in the row of null so it was ignored by the DataAdapter since no line had a null value in the database. I modded the code and got it running proper. 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/50355328/4801036

Comment: Just to add to the end of the selected answer, we can also set `RowState` to `Modified` by calling `dataTable.AcceptChanges(); dataTable.Rows[i].SetModified();`. The first command is required if the `row[i]` has `RowState` of `Added`, in which case the second command wild yield an Exception if done alone.

Answer (score 1):

Adapter will decide when insert, update or delete based on `DataRow.RowState` of each row in the table.
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datarowstate(v=vs.110).aspx for possible states.

After filling the DataTable you can call [DataTable.AcceptChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) method to mark all rows as unchanged.

Also, if you have autonumeric PK, is a best practice setting that field in DataTable with these properties:

- Autoincrement: true
- AutoIncrementSeed: -1

The last one ensure that if you insert new values in your datatable, the new ID values will not conflict with existing ones